# AllOrNoneHeader for Bulk API

Tags: rest-api, java, bulk-api

I am trying to switch off Autocommit feature by using AllOrNoneHeader in Bulk API implementation through JAVA. I have searched over internet but see only example of implementing it for SOAP based calls but nothing for Bulk API i.e. Restful service call

I need suggestion if there is any direct or indirect way to implement AllOrNoneHeader for Restful Bulk API Implementation,

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe this options exists for the bulk API. Based on [General Guidelines for Data Loads in the Bulk API documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/asynch_api_planning_guidelines.htm) I conclude it always executes in way similar to having **AllOrNone=false**.

> The Bulk API doesn't generate an error immediately when encountering a
>   lock. It waits a few seconds for its release and, if it doesn't
>   happen, the record is marked as failed. If there are problems
>   acquiring locks for more than 100 records in a batch, the Bulk API
>   places the remainder of the batch back in the queue for later
>   processing. When the Bulk API processes the batch again later, records
>   marked as failed are not retried. To process these records, you must
>   submit them again in a separate batch. If the Bulk API continues to
>   encounter problems processing a batch, it's placed back in the queue
>   and reprocessed up to 10 times before the batch is permanently marked
>   as failed. **Even if the batch failed, some records could have completed
>   successfully**. To get batch results to see which records, if any, were
>   processed, see Getting Batch Results. If errors persist, create a
>   separate job to process the data in serial mode, which ensures that
>   only one batch is processed at a time.